# Include in Entity Framework Core is not working properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to show the brand name and product color and product size in user basket. I use ASP.NET Core 3.1 for this project.

I used this query with `include`:

```
public IEnumerable<UserBasket> GetUserBasket(int userId)
    {
        return _context.UserBaskets
            .Include(p=>p.Product)
            .Include(b=>b.ProductBrand)
            .Include(s=>s.ProductSize)
            .Include(c=>c.ProductColor)
            .Where(u=>u.UserId==userId)
            .ToList();
    }
```

and this is the action:

```
public IActionResult ShowOrders()
{
    var userId = _userService.GetUserIdByUserName(User.Identity.Name);
    return View(_orderService.GetUserBasket(userId));
}
```

and this is the view of the action:

I used table to show the user basket

```
@model IEnumerable<UserBasket>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr class="gradeA odd">
                                <td class="sorting_1">@item.Product.Name</td>
                                <td class="center ">@item.Count</td>
                                <td class="center ">@item.SumPrice</td>
                                <td class="center ">@item.CreateDate.Value.ToShamsi()</td>
                                <td class="center ">@item.ProductBrand.BrandName</td>
                                <td class="center ">@item.Size</td>
                                <td class="center ">@item.Color</td>
                                @if (item.IsFinally)
                                {
                                    <td class="center "><i class="glyphicon-ok"></i></td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td class="center "><i class="glyphicon-remove"></i></td>
                                }
                            </tr>
                        }
```

This is UserBasket class:

```
public class UserBasket
{
    public UserBasket()
    {

    }
    [Key]
    public int UB_Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int PB_Id { get; set; }
    public int PC_Id { get; set; }
    public int PS_Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int SumPrice { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinally { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Size { get; set; }

    #region relations

    public virtual User.User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Product.Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductBrand ProductBrand { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductColor ProductColor { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductSize ProductSize { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This is Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {

    }
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int PB_Id { get; set; }
    public int PC_Id { get; set; }
    public int PS_Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int? Visit { get; set; }

    #region relations

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductBrand ProductBrand { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductColor ProductColor { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductSize ProductSize { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserBasket> UserBaskets { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This is the User class:

```
 public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        
    }
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ActiveCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }

    #region relations
    public virtual List<UserBasket> UserBaskets { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserOrder> UserOrders { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

when I run the project it shows

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

in view. What should I do?

Comment: could you pls  show us UserBasket class?

Comment: I edited the question with UserBasket class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine now.
I shouldn't use these in userbasket class:

```
 [Required]
[MaxLength(200)]
public string BrandName { get; set; }
[Required]
[MaxLength(200)]
public string Color { get; set; }
[Required]
[MaxLength(200)]
public string Size { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls change

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeA odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">@item.Product.Name</td>
            <td class=" ">@item.SumPrice</td>
            <td class="center ">@item.CreateDate</td>
            <td class="center ">@item.IsFinally</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
```

to

```
   <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model){
 
        <tr class="gradeA odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">@item.Product.Name</td>
            <td class=" ">@item.SumPrice</td>
            <td class="center ">@item.CreateDate</td>
            <td class="center ">@item.IsFinally</td>
        </tr>
   
}
 </tbody>
```

I guess that you each basket can have several products  so remove your ProductId from the UserBaskets table

```
   [Table("UserBaskets")]
public class UserBasket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SumPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinally { get; set; } 
    public int UserId { get; set; }
     public User User { get; set; }
}
```

and create the new class UserBasketProduct and add the product there

```
public class UserBasketProduct
{
public int UserBasketId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserBasket UserBasket{ get; set; }
 public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
.... add some properties to dbcontext
```

after this make the query according the  updated EF

Comment: If  each user buscket  has only one product according you EF or  each basket  can  have several productus?

Comment: The relations are true.I tested these models and the relations with another project.It worked fine and showed the product name too. Is it possible that the whole project or packages have problem and affect the query?

Comment: Since you productId as a foreigner key to your user basket your EF will be only working properly if your basket can have only one product. Is it true? The only way to keep many-to-many is an additional table. It can work like you have now but only if you keep everything in the memory.

Comment: Or another way  it will work like this if  your basket doesnt have a primariy key an you have to create the same busket for each product in this busket.

Comment: I think my vs or database has a problem. I copied the whole project into a new project and it worked fine but now I have account activation problem that I didn't have this problem in previous project.

Comment: I highly recommend you to install "EF Core Power Tools". After this you can create your code-first EF form your DB  using "Reverse Engeneer" option of  this tool. If you still don't have table UserBasketProduct in your DB create it before using tools. And please use the single names for you db table  name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your relationship is many-to-many between User and Products.

In my project, I successfully display multiple Product names. Here is my example:

UserBacket class:

```
public class UserBaskets
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SumPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinally { get; set; } 
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserBaskets> UserBaskets{ get; set; }
}
```

User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserBaskets> UserBaskets { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your View:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserBaskets>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeA odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">@item.Product.Name</td>
            <td class=" ">@item.SumPrice</td>
            <td class="center ">@item.CreateDate</td>
            <td class="center ">@item.IsFinally</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. it shows all the records I expect but it doesn't show the product name again.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing as you did but still not working and it shows only one record. Is it possible that the whole project or packages have problem?

Comment: First of all, the possibility of problems with the project or package is very small. What you have to do is to make sure that your relationship is correct, and then there are multiple pieces of data in the database. You can share your `User, Product, UserBackets` table with us. I am confused about `User.User` in your code `"public virtual User.User User {get; set; }"`.

Comment: I updated the question with these tables.The first User is the namespace. actually the relationship is like this. `public virtual User User {get; set; }`  I finally could show the product name view but now I have trouble showing BrandName and productSize and ProductColor in view.all the relations is like product and userbasket.I don't know why it is not working.